# C++: recursively computer all permutaions of digits 0 - 9

Tags: c++, permutation

I have a homework assignment where part of the requirement is to recursively compute all the permutations of integers 0 - 9. The professor actually gave us the algorithm for this part of the question. I've finished the rest of the assignment, but I can't get the permute function working...I'm implementing it exactly like it was shown on the assignment information. However, when I run it each permutation is repeated multiple times (and I'm not sure if I'm even getting all the correct permutations.)

I think he must've made a mistake on the assignment instructions. I've been working on this for a couple of hours and can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. Can anybody help point me in the right direction?

Here's the current code:

```
void permute(int v[], int curr) {
    for (int i = curr; i < MAX; i++) {
        swap(v[i], v[curr]);
        permute(v, curr + 1);
        swap(v[curr], v[i]);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Actually, right after posting this I realized it has to do with the swap, right? Because right now i and curr are the same, so I'm swapping identical numbers. Hm, should it be swap(v[i], v[curr+1])?

Comment: What is the problem specifically? You also might want to add `if (curr == MAX) //print array `

Comment: amit: I think that may have actually helped. I was including a print statement to check, but just realized that it was before reaching MAX. I think that's where I was getting confused. Let me try it with using if(cur==max) and see what I get.

Comment: You code looks fine so far. It should work in the current form. Maybe you print too often? You should only print if `curr==MAX`.

Comment: Howard: yeah, I think that was the problem. amit's comment helped me realize that. I just tried printing after curr==max, and I seem to be getting the expected values. Thanks!

Comment: Just to verify, the total amount of permutations I should get is 10! or 3628800, right? I'm running the code now to make sure that's how many I end up with.

Comment: @Nate: You can use a `static int` that increases whenever you reach `curr == MAX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping my comments [which seems to solve the OP's issue] as an answer:

(1) You might want to print your array when you reach max:

```
if (curr == MAX) //print array
```

(2) You might want to count the number of permutations you get, you can do it by having a `static int` [or a global variable, or an extra parameter `int& count`] - and increase it whenever `curr == MAX` [along with printing].